# Swift get value from UnsafeMutablePointer<Void> using UnsafePointer<String>

Tags: pointers, swift, reference, dereference

I am trying to pass `contextInfo` of type`UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>` to `UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum` and use it in the callback function.  For some reason I am unable to access `contextInfo` as a string using `UnsafePointer<String>(x).memory` when I am in the callback function.

I am pretty sure it is something simple I am missing but have spent way to many hours trying to figure this out.

Below is some code that I have tried.

The following code works.

```
var testStr:String = "hello"
takesAMutableVoidPointer(&testStr)

func takesAMutableVoidPointer(x: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>){
    var pStr:String = UnsafePointer<String>(x).memory
    println("x = \(x)")
    println("pStr = \(pStr)")
}
```

However the following code does not work.

```
var testStr:String = "hello"

if UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(filePath){ //the filePath is compatible
    println("Compatible")
    //UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(filePath, self, nil, nil)
    UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(filePath, self, "video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:", &testStr)
}
else{
    println("Not Compatible")
}

func video(video: NSString, didFinishSavingWithError error:NSError, contextInfo:UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>){
    var pStr:String = UnsafePointer<String>(contextInfo).memory
    println("contextInfo = \(contextInfo)")
    println("pStr = \(pStr)")
}
```

Once I get to the following line:

```
var pStr:String = UnsafePointer<String>(contextInfo).memory
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x0)
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

**Update**

Rintaro commented that testStr needs to be top level but the following code works.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        var testStr:String = "hello"
        takesAMutableVoidPointer(&testStr)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func takesAMutableVoidPointer(x: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>){
        var answer = UnsafePointer<String>(x).memory
        println("x = \(x)")
        println("answer = \(answer)")
    }
}
```

I am trying not to use global variables unless I have to.  I may have to but since I am able to execute the above code, it seems as though I do not need to use a global variable.

Comment: Where do you declare `testStr`? It's need to be statically allocated. So, I think, it should be at top-level.

Comment: I can define testStr in a function, then pass its reference to another function and get the contents of the reference in the other function.  That already works.  I believe that means that it does not have to be 'top-level'.  But I may not understand what you mean by 'top-level'.  The issue is it does not work when using UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum.  The function is called.  It gets into the function.  I can even print the memory address, but I cannot get the contents of the memory address.

Comment: Your updated code performs synchronous call. In this case,  `testStr` remains on memory until the end of `viewDidLoad` method. But, `UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum` notifies the callback asynchronously, and `testStr` has been freed at that time.

Comment: Oh ok, that makes sense.  Is there any way to force the retaining of a variable that has been created in a function?  Then release it later?  I ask because in obj-c i was able to create a `NSString*` variable in a function then pass it as the contextInfo param to `UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum`.  I did cast it as `(__bridge void *)` though.  I do not think that had any bearing on the retaining of the variable, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As discussed in OP comments, `testStr` has already been freed.

> Is there any way to force the retaining of a variable that has been created in a function? Then release it later?

It's not impossible, but I don't know this is the best way to do that.

Anyway, try this with Playground or OS X "Command Line Tool" template:

```
import Foundation

func foo() {
    var str:NSString = "Hello World"
    let ptr = UnsafePointer<Void>(Unmanaged<NSString>.passRetained(str).toOpaque())
    bar(ptr)
}

func bar(v:UnsafePointer<Void>) {
    let at = dispatch_time(
        DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
        Int64(2.0 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
    )
    dispatch_after(at, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        baz(v)
    }
}

func baz(v:UnsafePointer<Void>) {
    println("notified")
    let str = Unmanaged<NSString>.fromOpaque(COpaquePointer(v)).takeRetainedValue()
    println("info: \(str)")
}


foo()

println("started")

dispatch_main()
```

- `Unmanaged<NSString>.passRetained(str)` increments the retain count.
- `Unmanaged<NSString>.fromOpaque(...).takeRetainedValue()` decrements it, and extract the object.

I think, using *pure* Swift `String` is impossible. because `String` is `struct` and is allocated in stack memory. Maybe the buffer of it is allocated in heap, but we cannot access it directly.

Comment: Thanks!  I really appreciate your help.  I must admit, it seems a bit unsettling that there is no way to pass contextInfo to UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum in swift with out using a global variable or 'jumping through hoops' like above to retain a variable.