# Pass dictionary through addObserver context parameter?

Tags: swift

I need to observe the status of an `AVPlayer`, so I add an observer:

```
let player = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: tempFilePath))
player.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options: nil, context: nil)
```

And observe the change with the relevant function:

```
override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String, ofObject object: AnyObject, change: [NSObject : AnyObject], context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    if object is AVPlayer {
        var player = object as! AVPlayer
        player.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status")
    }
}
```

This is working fine, however, I need to some more information in the `observeValueForKeyPath` function, namely a dictionary:

```
var context = [
    "layer": CALayer(),
    "filePath": String()
]
```

Consequently, I figured I could pass that dictionary under the context parameter, since:

> The context pointer can be used as a unique identifier to determine the change that is being observed, or to provide some other data to the observer ([Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOBasics.html))

I'm not entirely sure how to pass the `context` variable, which has a `[String, AnyObject]` type as an `UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>` type.

Reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26776662/swift-get-value-from-unsafemutablepointervoid-using-unsafepointerstring), I figured I could do something like:

```
UnsafeMutablePointer(Unmanaged.passUnretained(context).toOpaque())
...
Unmanaged<[String, AnyObject]>.fromOpaque(COpaquePointer(context)).takeUnretainedValue()
```

But not surprisingly, that didn't work. I also figured I could pass the variable by reference, `&context`, but I was unable to decode the address of the original variable. Is this where `NSCoder` is used?

Comment: You are passing an *unretained* object pointer around, which works only if a reference to the context dictionary is held somewhere (otherwise it might have been destroyed when the callback method is called). Did you try it with a *retained* reference (as suggested in the linked answer)?

Comment: @MartinR makes sense. I passed it as an `NSDictionary` (but not a `Dictionary`?) by using `UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>(Unmanaged<NSDictionary>.passRetained(context).toOpaque())`, and then reading it with, `Unmanaged<NSDictionary>.fromOpaque(COpaquePointer(context)).takeRetainedValue()`. Is this acceptable? Also, do I now need to release context?

Comment: I think that is all explained in the answer to the linked question. passRetained increases the refcount and takeRetainedValue decreases it, so they must be properly balanced.